# Automapper: ignore property on inherited class

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-4

I have a source class like this:

```
public class Basket {}
```

a target class like this:

```
public class BasketModel 
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

and a mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Basket, BasketModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Property, o => o.ResolveUsing(x => "anything"));
```

Now I've made the "Property" property in the original model virtual and created a new class that inherits from the model:

```
public class BasketModel 
{
    public virtual string Property { get; set; }
}
public class BasketModel2 : BasketModel
{
    public override string Property 
    { 
        get
        {
            return "some value";
        }
    }
}
```

I've updated the mapping as such:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Basket, BasketModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Property, o => o.ResolveUsing(x => "anything"))
    .Include<Basket, BasketModel2>();
```

And created the mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Basket, BasketModel2>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Property, o => o.Ignore());
```

Now when I try to map into BasketModel2, instead of `null`, the value of Property is `"anything"`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @bommelding thanks, fixed it

Comment: And the really are both called 'Property' ?  Why design a model with a name-conflict? Is tat the core question?

Comment: I clearly did a bad job at bringing the actual code back to its minimum... I've edited it again. I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I had a brainfart when I wrote this code. model2.Property is never going to be null because it's a getter that always returns the same string. I have some refactoring to do, but AutoMapper was doing what it needs to do, I was just using it wrong.